# how to update a one to many relationship Flask SQLAlchemy database

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a one to many relationship Postgres SqlAlchemy model. I've been able to deal with the CRD of CRUD model , my problem is how to update items from the Position table

```
class Members(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'members'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    middle_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    surname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    maiden_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    gender = db.Column(db.String(100))
    phone_number = db.Column(db.String(100))
    second_phone_number = db.Column(db.String(100))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100))
    residential_address = db.Column(db.String(100))
    state_of_origin = db.Column(db.String(100))
    state_lga = db.Column(db.String(100))
    date_of_birth = db.Column(db.Date)
    permanent_address = db.Column(db.String(100))
    occupation = db.Column(db.String(100))
    marital_status = db.Column(db.String(100))
    wedding_date = db.Column(db.String(100))
    baptism = db.Column(db.String(100))
    society = db.Column(db.String(100))
    positions = db.relationship('Position', backref='member', lazy = "dynamic" , cascade = "all,delete")

class Position(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'positions'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    position = db.Column(db.String(100))
    department = db.Column(db.String(100))
    start_date = db.Column(db.String(100))
    end_date = db.Column(db.String(100))
    member_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('members.id'))
```

Here's what my Edit looks like ,items from the Members table works fine when edited and committed to the database however I can't seem to find my way around making Position items work .

```
def edit(id):
    member_id = Members.query.get(id)
    position = Position.query.filter(Position.member_id == id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        member_id.first_name = request.form['first_name']
        member_id.middle_name = request.form['middle_name']
        member_id.surname = request.form['surname']
        member_id.gender = request.form['gender']
        member_id.marital_status = request.form['marital_status']
        member_id.maiden_name = request.form['maiden_name']
        member_id.phone_number = request.form['phone_number']
        member_id.second_phone_number = request.form['second_phone_number']
        member_id.email = request.form['email']
        member_id.residential_address = request.form['address']
        member_id.state_of_origin = request.form['state']
        member_id.state_lga = request.form['lga']
        member_id.permanent_address = request.form['permanent_address']
        member_id.occupation = request.form['occupation']
        member_id.baptism = request.form['baptism']
        member_id.society = request.form['society']
        member_id.date_of_birth = request.form['dob']
        member_id.wedding_date = request.form['wedding_date']

#Position should go here
        db.session.commit()
```